# Rails simple_calendar rendering unwanted data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using simple_calendar in my Rails 5.0 application to link to events, everything works fine except that I get some extra data rendered in the calendar, I would like to get some help to figure it out.
This is what I have in the 'views/eventos/calendario.html.erb'

```
<h3>Eventos (<%= @eventos.count %>)</h3>
<%= month_calendar events: @eventos do |date, eventos| %>
  <%= date.day %>
  <% eventos.each do |evento| %>
    <div>
      <%= link_to evento.tipoEvento, evento %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And this is what it is rendering for each day with programmed events:

```
<td class="day wday-5 past current-month has-events">

  9
    <div>
      <a href="/eventos/4">Entrenamiento</a>
    </div>
    [#&lt;Evento id: 4, fecha: "2016-12-09", tipoEvento:
    "Entrenamiento", equipo_id: 11, comment: "Cancha 2", 
    created_at: "2016-12-08 06:07:19", updated_at: "2016-12-08
    06:22:03", registrado: true&gt;]
</td>
```

For days without events it is rendering the empty []. See, it is rendering the correct  tag but I don't know how to avoid it rendering the object data, Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to replace a line in the generated view: views/simple_calendar/_month_calendar.html.erb
from:

```
<%= block.call day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []) %>
```

to:

```
<% block.call day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []) %>
```

So Jagdeep's answer was right, but in a different code line.